# mongodb on VMPlayer ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongoDB on ubuntu in VMplayer running on windows7.

I have edited the hosts file to have

> machinename   192.168.1.12.

I installed all the packages and trying to start the mongod.
This is the error I am getting:

> ubuntu:/etc/init.d$ start mongodb start: Rejected send message, 1
>   matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.128" (uid=1000 pid=9669
>   comm="start mongodb ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
>   member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
>   destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Can you please let me know what could be the issue?
I was able to install successfully in a pevious in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

That's a permission error, you need to sudo, i.e. run the following and you will be ok -

sudo start mongodb